# Select children of specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
    <div class="A">
    </div>
    <div class="B">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select children of row class whose classes are col-md-4,6,8,12. Is there any good way to select all at once?

There can be multiple row divs and I am going to use wrapAll to wrap every row div's children in some other div. So if I use wrapAll, it just shifts all content of other row divs to the first row div. If I put the selector query inside loop, it just keeps wrapping the children times the number of row divs. I don't want to let this happen.

**Are you understanding guys?**

Comment: Yes there is. But what did you try??

Comment: `$('.col-md-4,.col-md-6,.col-md-8,........ ').children()`

Comment: Did you find any of the answers below useful? If so, please consider up-voting and/or marking them as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

#### A non-javascript solution

Try selecting them with the `^` or with the `*` selector. For example like:

```
[class^="col-md-"] {}
```

That will select elements with a class that **starts** with `col-md-`, thus, making the number at the end irrelevant.

or

```
[class*="col-md-"] {}
```

That will select elements with a class that contain `col-md-`.

Here's what the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) says:

> **[attr^=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr the
>   value of which is prefixed by "value".
>
> ---
>
> **[attr*=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr the value of which contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

---

#### Demo:

```css
.row [class^="col-md-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="A">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="B">
      foo bar
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete, that's right. The class attribute would have to *start* with the `col-md-`.

Comment: @Pete, okay, added another option.

Answer (score 0):

if You have other child elements with `col-md-*` and you do not want to target them. Then can use descendant child selector or `.find()`:

```
$('.row .col-md-4,.row .col-md-6 ')
```

or

```
$('.row').find('.col-md-4,.col-md-6,.col-md-8,.col-md-12')
```

Otherwise you can use attribute contains selector:

```
$('.row [class*="col-md-"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use native 'querySelectorAll' function.

Like that :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.row [class*="col-md"]')
```

**[class*="col-md"]** means "All classes containing 'col-md"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row>[class|="col-md"]')
```

.row is a class selector

> is a children selector

[] is a attribute selector

|= means prefix is

The code means that select the children of those with class "row", whose value of attribute class have a prefix "col-md".

Note1: according to the recommended rules, the value part of the attribute select (no matter it is a equals relation, prefix equals or other kinds of equals), the part after =, should be a string. Since the select has already been a string in '', you need to use "" to describe a string.
But if you use "" make the selector string, inside you need to use '' as a string.

Note 2: I just tried |="col-md-" but it does not work.